# Fetching Records in DB using Angular JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, database, angularjs

I am working on a application which is built only on Angular JS technology. Could you please let me know will there be any way for  accessing the DB which will be hosted on different server and parse the result based on requirement. I have chance of using only technologies like Angular JS, jquery, Java Script(Client Technologies only).

Comment: Look into the MEAN stack. http://meanjs.org/

Answer (score 0):

You need to be more specific. What database are you using?
In general, you will need an API for the database you can connect to using AJAX calls.

Comment: Its normal data base like ORACLE database. Could you give me an example if possible please.?

Comment: It cannot be done to my knowledge using only client side technologies. You will need to develop a backend that executes the SQL requests and provides an HTTP interface.